# css: Making background image fit height and width of div

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

in bootstrap template i'm adding an image as background like this

```
background:url(../images/banner.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
```

problem with these css  rules is that images is getting clipped only showing center part of  the image which is as per height of the div where its added  i want image to be shown to its full height instead of small center part only .

see screenshot for better understanding

[image]

Comment: If image is 400px tall and `div` is only 100px tall, how will it show the image fully? You'd need to increase the height of your `div` also then. Unlike with `content`, background image's size cannot affect the `div` height (that is, it cannot make the `div` expand to fit the image).

Comment: cant we squeeze the image height using css ?

Comment: But squeezing wouldn't be same as showing full height of image, so question should be modified.

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

will give you the result you wanted.

***But I don't recommend it.***

Comment: It will. Because you wanted to squeeze the image. That is not a good practice. You have to maintain the aspect ratio of the image. In that case, you have to sacrifice some part of the image. So, `background-size: cover;` is the best way

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
background-size: contain;
```

Comment: height is fit  but width is not how to make that fit to width as well

Answer (score 0):

Try your code to this.

```
background:url(../images/banner.png);
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
```

And add this.

```
html{
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/v1SabYdIlZI/maxresdefault.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
background : url (../images/banner.png) no-repeat; 
background-size:contain;
```